# change Visual Studio project root?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

My project has all the visual studio solutions and projects stored in ./win/vc100, sources in ./src/ and libraries in ./lib/

Now if I want to add additional libraries to include I need to specify the path as ../../lib/library_name

Is there any way to set the root to be at . rather than ./win/vc100 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can't, sorry (maybe except for some magical hacks into MSBuild which would be much worse than typing a few ../../ )

Comment: Guess we're stuck with the ../../ or we could define some kind of macro to use with it. well thanks for your question anyway.